# Android GCM Notification Backstack

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, back-stack

I set up GCM on android and I'm able to receive notifications correctly. In the notification I'm setting the "click_action" so that android opens a specific activity (`ListActivity`) for me when selecting the Notification. This is all working great.

However if the user left the app by pressing back, when the new activity is launched (by gcm) the whole back stack is missing. Here is my android manifest and also an example of how I send the notifications.

AndriodManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".views.HomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".views.ListActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".views.HomeActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_LIST"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".views.HomeActivity"/>
</activity>
```

Notification example

```
curl -X POST https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization:key=AUTHORIZATION_KEY" \
-d '{
  "to" : "GCM_TOKEN",
  "priority" : "high",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "Notification body",
    "title" : "Notification Title",
    "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_LIST"
  },
  "data": {
    "message": "Please open an activity with a backstack configured!"
  }
}'
```

Is it possible to have gcm to create the back stack automatically for me? If so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you Paste your ListActivity Code. Or can you added Back Event in listviewActivity

Comment: Hi @jigspatel, currently the ListActivity is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I found this interesting [website](https://docs.intercom.io/install-on-your-mobile-product/using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-with-intercom-for-android). Take a look at [Step 5](https://docs.intercom.io/install-on-your-mobile-product/using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-with-intercom-for-android#step-5-open-intercom-conversations-from-gcm). I think it is what you are looking for.

> To allow a cloud message to open the app and jump straight to an Intercom message we need to get the intent data sent to us. In your apps launch activity (the first activity it will go to) add the following. You should call this method early in the Activity life-cycle such as onCreate.
>
> ```
> Intercom.client().openGCMMessage(getIntent());
> ```
>
> If you wish to create a custom back stack for this notification you can pass a TaskStackBuilder to the same method:
>
> ```
> openGCMMessage(Intent intent, TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder);
> ```

Comment: Hello @gerardnimo, the solution you are suggesting involves using Intercom and I want to go purely GCM. I believe that under the hood Intercom is creating the Notification in the Drawer with a TaskStackBuilder, and that is something I could do myself. What I want is to have GCM to automatically create the back stack.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible as far as the documentations are concerned. If it is a functionality already available for GCM you should be able to at least find it in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution I've found is to override

> onCreateSupportNavigateUpTaskStack

in the Activity